# Unexpected grid Lines in ListPlot

Tags: plotting, grid-layouts

Why is Mathematica plotting a horizontal line at $y=2$ in the following example:

```
ListPlot[Table[i,{i,1,10}],Frame->True,GridLines->None]
```

[image: Output]

How to get rid of this line?

Comment: Try restarting your kernel. It doesn't plot a line like that for me. If the problems persist, please tell us what operating system and version of Mathematica you are using.

Comment: @Anon It does in `Mathematica 7` but it doesn't in newer versions.

Comment: @Anon: Its 8.0.0.0, Linux x86 (64-bit). This problem is always there, kernel restart does not help.

Comment: Does including  `Axes -> {False, True}` or `AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}` have the desired effect (I am using Mma 7)?

Comment: @TomD: it works, thank you!

Comment: @TomD Sounds like you should turn that into an answer.

Comment: @TomD is correct, but it is much simpler to use `Axes -> False` since I doubt you want the y-axis. However, there are plots I've made where both frame and axes are used.

Comment: @rcollyer were you able to put `FrameTicks` and `Ticks` simultaneously?

Comment: @Kuba I never tried that as I was using them effectively as `GridLines`, so `Ticks` did not matter. However, trying `Plot[{x, x^2}, {x, -1, 1}, Frame -> True, Axes -> True, 
 Ticks -> {Range[-1, 1, 0.25], Range[-1, 1, 0.25]} ]` reveals that, no it seems you can't. :P

Comment: @rcollyer Yes I know and I was thinking lately why. That's not obvious so if one forget to `Axes->False` the axes are not well recognizable :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**TL;DR**

What you see is the `x` axis, it is not the `GridLine` so `Axes->False` is the fix.

Or rather it is what you have missed because by default `Axes->True` and it was just a coincidence that it was observed only for V7 users.

---

The reason why others do not see this in newer versions is only this that the `Automatic` `AxesOrigin` is generated in different place.

To reproduce this behaviour in V9 other simply need to add this:

```
ListPlot[Table[i, {i, 1, 10}], Frame -> True, GridLines -> None, 
                               AxesOrigin -> {0, 2}]
```

[image]

$y$ axis is overlayed by `Frame` so it is "not" visible.

---

It could be quite confusing because **with `Frame->True` you can't put `Ticks` on axes** so single line do not look like and axis at all.

Even if one set `FrameTicks->None`... interesting, but it is different issue so let's not talk about it here.

```
ListPlot[Table[i, {i, 1, 10}], Frame -> True, GridLines -> None, 
                               FrameTicks -> None, AxesOrigin -> {2, 2}, 
                               Ticks -> True]
```

[image]