# Ticks on axes with a frame without frameticks

Tags: plotting, graphics, output-formatting, ticks

I would like to draw a simple 2D graphics with a frame, without any FrameTicks, but still having central axes with ticks.  The code is this :

```
Plot[
LegendreP[3, x], {x, -1, 1},
PlotPoints -> Automatic,
PlotRange -> {-1, 1},
PlotStyle -> Directive[Thick, RGBColor[0.00, 0.40, 0.80]],
Frame -> True,
FrameTicks -> None,
Axes -> True,
Ticks -> True,
AxesOrigin -> {0, 0},
AxesStyle -> Directive[Gray],
GridLines -> Automatic,
GridLinesStyle -> Directive[Gray, Dashed],
Ticks -> Automatic,
PerformanceGoal -> "Quality"
]
```

I believed that would be easy and pretty standard.  Apparently, I was wrong (?).  The documentation didn't tell anything about this combination, and the site didn't helped me much with this.

So how do you add ticks on both central axes ?  The command `Ticks -> True` doesn't seem to make a diference.

Comment: The short answer is that you can't have both axis ticks and a frame in the built-in system, perhaps because it can be confusing to the casual reader. This has been discussed before here: [FrameTicks and Ticks on Axes in Same Plot](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/44598/27951), where some sophisticated workarounds are provided as well. A very simple alternative could be to wrap your `Plot` in `Framed`: [image](http://i.stack.imgur.com/6OcUj.png).

Comment: So we can't have both at the same time ?  This is weird.  In a Manipulate box, the FrameTicks are taking space outside the frame.  Inside the frame, it would be ugly.  The graphics with axes + ticks but without a frame is uglier.

Comment: Doh !  Using `PlotRange -> {{-1, 1}, {-1, 1}}`without a Frame is a good compromise.

Comment: Try [`Framed`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Framed.html).

Comment: You have used the Ticks option twice.

Answer (score 5):

Since all you want is a frame, use [Framed](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Framed.html)

```
Framed[Plot[LegendreP[3, x], {x, -1, 1},
  PlotRange -> All,
  PlotStyle -> Directive[Thick,
    RGBColor[0.00, 0.40, 0.80]],
  Axes -> True,
  GridLines -> Automatic,
  GridLinesStyle ->
   Directive[Gray, Dashed],
  Ticks -> True,
  PerformanceGoal -> "Quality"]]
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Maybe by using the Overlay command for two plots: one without frame and another one without axes

```
   Overlay[{Plot[LegendreP[3, x], {x, -1, 1}, PlotPoints -> Automatic, 
   PlotRange -> Full, 
   PlotStyle -> Directive[Thick, RGBColor[0.00, 0.40, 0.80]], 
   Frame -> False, Axes -> True, AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}, 
   AxesStyle -> Directive[Gray], GridLines -> Automatic, 
   GridLinesStyle -> Directive[Gray, Dashed], Ticks -> Automatic, 
   PerformanceGoal -> "Quality", ImagePadding -> All, Frame -> True], 
   Plot[None, {x, -1, 1}, PlotPoints -> Automatic, PlotRange -> Full, 
   PlotStyle -> Directive[Thick, RGBColor[0.00, 0.40, 0.80]], 
   Frame -> True, FrameTicks -> None, Axes -> False, Ticks -> True, 
   AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}, AxesStyle -> Directive[Gray], 
   Ticks -> Automatic, PerformanceGoal -> "Quality"]}]
```

[image]