# Is it possible to have axes ticks with frame?

Tags: plotting, ticks, frame

For example,

```
Plot[x^3, {x, -1, 1}]
```

gives ticks on both axes, and

```
Plot[x^3, {x, -1, 1},Frame->True]
```

gives ticks on the frame. Is it possible to have ticks on  the axes with the framed plot?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: [related or duplicate](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/44604/5467). In short, use `Overlay` . Try `gr00=Plot[x^3, {x, -1, 1},ImagePadding->20];
gr01=Plot[x^3, {x, -1, 1},Frame->True,ImagePadding->20];
Overlay[{gr00,gr01}]`

Comment: Thank you for your response even though duplicated, I saw the answer at your link, but it was more complicated and I'm under too much of a deadline to try to figure out what is what in that answer. Your minimal example worked perfectly with small modifications! I needed overlay=50, and changed the font color of the frame ticks to white to eliminate the numbering on the bottom frame. Thanks again! – Sureau 1 hour ago

Comment: Does `Framed[Plot[x^3, {x, -1, 1}]]` do what you want?

Comment: No, I like having the frame ticks. It allow you to line up a straight edge and approximate data points with complicated graphs. But thanks for your suggestion.