# Get Ticks both in Frame as in Axes

Tags: plotting, code-review, plot-themes

Why have the numbers disappeared from in the $X$ `Axis` ?

Is there some way to keep the `Frame` and having the numbers on the `Axis`?

```
Plot[
 {
  f[10, 1, 1, 2, 0, t]
  }
 , {t, 0, 19}
 , PlotRange -> {-5, 2}
 , LabelStyle -> {FontSize -> 22, FontFamily -> "Times", Black, Bold}
 , PlotStyle -> {{Darker[Blue], 
    Thickness[0.004]}, {Darker[Blue]}, {Darker[Blue]}, {Darker[
     Blue]}, {Darker[Blue]}}
 , PlotRangePadding -> 0
 , LabelStyle -> {FontSize -> 13}
 , AxesStyle -> Bold
 , Frame -> True
 , FrameLabel -> {t[sec], \[ScriptCapitalD]'[t]}
 , LabelStyle -> {FontSize -> 13}
 , AxesStyle -> Bold
 , FrameStyle -> {{Directive[FontColor -> Darker[Red]], 
    Automatic}, {Directive[FontColor -> Darker[Red]], Automatic}}
 ]
```

[image]

Comment: Using Frame for the plot causes this. This is expected. Compare Plot[Sin[x], {x, -6, 6}] and Plot[Sin[x], {x, -6, 6}, Frame -> True]

Comment: @Lotus Is there some way to keep the frame and having the numbers on the axis?

Comment: Look at [this question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/44598/frameticks-and-ticks-on-axes-in-same-plot) for putting both frame ticks and axis ticks on the same plot. Also, note that you are using some style commands (as LabelStyle) more than once, and this is in general a bad practice.