# How can I use Frame and axes on the same plot?

Tags: plotting

It is necessary to display the Frame (in the left edge of the plot) and usual axes (in the bottom) in the same plot. *Mathematica* doesn't support this feature as discussed earlier. But there is a [workaround](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/44598/frameticks-and-ticks-on-axes-in-same-plot) that tackles the problem with the use of `Overlay` function. In my example, unfortunately, zigzag lines are shifted a bit

```
Overlay[{ListLinePlot[{2, 3, 1, 4, 2}, Frame -> {{True, False}, {False, False}}, ImageSize -> 600],ListLinePlot[{2, 3, 1, 4, 2}, Ticks -> {{2, 3, 4}, None}, Axes -> {True, False}, ImageSize -> 600]}]
```

Is it possible to eliminate the offset?

Comment: Perhaps if you used the same `ImagePadding` on all of the plots, like `ImagePadding -> {{10, 10}, {10, 10}}`. You'll have to tinker with what values to choose to make it so that nothing gets cut off and the margins aren't too large. But, how "minimal" is this example? Are you really plotting the same function?  There might be a way to do this with just one single call to a plotting function, so it might be worth posting your actual code here.

Comment: "Mathematica doesn't support this feature as discussed earlier" - please provide a hyperlink so that the rest of us can be caught up to speed.

Comment: Your example looks very much like `ListLinePlot[{2, 3, 1, 4, 2}, Frame -> {{True, False}, {True, False}}, FrameTicks -> {Automatic, {{2, 3, 4}, None}}]`.

Comment: Have you tried using ```Show[{ListLinePlot[{2, 3, 1, 4, 2}, 
   Frame -> {{True, False}, {False, False}}, ImageSize -> 600], 
  ListLinePlot[{2, 3, 1, 4, 2}, Ticks -> {{2, 3, 4}, None}, 
   Axes -> {True, False}, ImageSize -> 600]}]```

Comment: Thanks, Jason. Your code with addition Axes->False (in order to hide axis in general case) works fine. Thank you to all contributors, your suggestions were useful.