# Axis is hidden when plotting with Frame option

Tags: plotting, graphics, frame

When plotting with Frame->True option, the axis is hidden when it is too close to the boundary of the plot. For example:

```
Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 10}, PlotRange -> {-0.1, 1}, Frame -> True]
```

[image: X-axis is hidden]

But if I increase the range, the x-axis can appear.

```
Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 10}, PlotRange -> {-0.2, 1}, Frame -> True]
```

[image: X-axis is not hidden]

How to force Mathematica to show the X-axis in the first case without changing the plotting range?

Comment: I have tried assigning AxesOrigin -> {0, 0} but it doesn't work.

Comment: Thanks for the check, couldn't try myself from a phone.

Comment: Inversely related: [(32189)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/32189/121)

Answer (score 13):

We can easily show that this is not a feature of `Plot` but of `Graphics` itself:

```
Graphics[Circle[], Frame -> True, Axes -> True, AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}, 
   PlotRange -> {{0, 1}, {#, 1}}] & /@ {-1/9, -1/9 - 0.00000001}
```

[image]

So it seems that the axis line is suppressed at 1/9 of the range of the plot.  This holds in both directions and at other scales:

```
Graphics[
   {Circle[], Circle[{2, 2}, 2]}, Frame -> True, Axes -> True, 
   AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}, PlotRange -> {2 {#, 1}, 4 {#, 1}}
] & /@ {-1/9, -1/9 - 0.00000001}
```

[image]

I suspect that this was intentionally programmed into `Graphics` to reduce plot clutter.

I recommend the use of [`GridLines`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/GridLines.html) in its place:

```
Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 10}, PlotRange -> {-0.1, 1}, Frame -> True, 
 GridLines -> {{0}, {0}}, GridLinesStyle -> Black]
```

[image]